# How to change the java platform to 1.5 when you have 1.6 in netbeans

Tags: netbeans, java

I have to install object store for a school project and it doesn't work with the 1.6 jdk. So I have this error:

```
Error: The format of class 'inventairePackage/Joueur' is of type JDK 1.6.  
Classes of this format cannot be currently annotated.
```

I use Netbeans and I don't know how to change the Java Platform because when I try to install the 1.5 jdk, it says that I can't because I use a higher version and in Netbeans I just have the option for the 1.6 jdk.

Thank you

Comment: it's what I thought. I was wondering if there's another way

Comment: what version of Netbeans are you using? you download the 1.5 jdk and tried to point your project to that jdk?

Comment: Im using netbeans 6.9.1 and I downloaded 1.5 jdk exe and when I try to install it, it doesn't work.

Comment: You downloaded it from here (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html#jdk-1.5.0_22-oth-JPR)? What error do you have when you double-click the executable?

Comment: But...why do you think you need 1.5 btw? I don't get why your 1.6 jdk project wouldn't accept a class `of type JDK 1.6`...

Comment: I fixed it, it was probably the wrong link. Thanks talnicolas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I downloaded from [talnicolas' link to oracle downloads](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase5-419410.html#jdk-1.5.0_22-oth-JPR) and everything works now.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Try switching the Source Binary Format to JDK 5 in your project properties.
(You don't need to have JDK 5 installed for this)